# Enter Key press event detect from textbox - Unity3D - C#

Tags: c#, unity, gui

i am doing a project with Unity3D . in the interface there is a textbox. once user input some text and and press enter key then i want to read the text in text box. so please tell me how to  programmatically detect the key press event in unity3D - C# using MonoDeveloper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little tricky. It's pretty confusing if you have a solid background with the web platform, JavaScript and DOM Events in partcular, where most of the events are abstractized in closures for each control.

In Unity, the Events are fired globally on `GUI`. You must then check them, and act accordingly.

#### Theory

- while the `GUIWindow` is drawn, listen for your [EventType](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventType.html) on `Event.current` (the event that just happened).
- if needed, check it against your GUI controls.
- if all the requirements have been matched, do something.

#### Implementation

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Somegui : MonoBehaviour
{

private string inputValue = "";
private bool windowShouldBeDrawnCondition = false;

void Update()
{
    // open dialog upon Enter
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
    {
        windowShouldBeDrawnCondition = !windowShouldBeDrawnCondition;
    }
}

void OnGUI()
{
    if (windowShouldBeDrawnCondition)
    {
        // draw dialog
        GUILayout.Window(0, new Rect(100, 100, 200, 0), DrawMyWindow, "Window Title");
    }
}

void DrawMyWindow(int windowID)
{
    // check for keydown event
    if (Event.current.type == EventType.KeyDown)
    {
        // no matter where, but if Escape was pushed, close the dialog
        if (Event.current.keyCode == KeyCode.Escape)
        {
            windowShouldBeDrawnCondition = false;
            return; // no point in continuing if closed
        }
        
        // we look if the event occured while the focus was in our input element
        if (GUI.GetNameOfFocusedControl() == "input" && Event.current.keyCode == KeyCode.Return)
        {
            SubmitInputValue();
        }
    }
    
    GUI.SetNextControlName("input");
    inputValue = GUILayout.TextField(inputValue);

    // in case nothing else if focused, focus our input
    if (GUI.GetNameOfFocusedControl() == string.Empty)
    {
        GUI.FocusControl("input");
    }
}

private void SubmitInputValue()
{       
    // do not proceed if empty
    if (inputValue.Length > 0)
    {
            // do something
        Debug.Log(inputValue);

        inputValue = ""; // usually, upon sending, the field should be reset
    }
}
}
```

Cannot test this at the moment, but it should work.

I have given, I hope, pretty understandable and reasonable comments to grasp what is fully going on there.